# Terragrunt installation

Tags: terragrunt

I am following this link [install terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/install/) to install Terragrunt and got this error `C:\Users\OMAR>terragrunt 'terragrunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I downloaded Terragrunt version `0.45.0` which is compatible with my existing Terraform `1.4` according to this [Terraform Version Compatibility Table](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/supported-terraform-versions/).

After that I added Terragrunt path to my windows environment path
[terragrunt path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDOkB.png), but i still facing the same error. I tried to add full path `C:\terragrunt\terragruntxxx.exe` but this didn't work.

I've searched around but got nothing, this is a an unexpected problem because did the same steps to add a install `Terraform` and worked, but with `Terragrunt` didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions. I tested the latest version of Terragrunt and from where I am located the file runs correctly (with and without the exe extension). At first, my antivirus tried to block the file, so check your antivirus software.